# Is there a way to get a separate console windows in Netbeans? One for build messages and one purely for program output?

Tags: netbeans, console

I am new to this forum and this is my first question. I am learning Java and have installed Java JDK 16 and Apache Netbeans IDE 12.3.

To get my feet wet I created a small "Java with Maven" project (I don't know anything about Maven so that is something else I need to learn). When I run the project the console window (Output tab) is flooded with build messages which makes it difficult to see the output from my program.

Does anyone know if there is a way to have a separate console window just for program output?

I've performed general searches, searched this forum and looked through the Netbeans help but I have yet to find a way to do this. Is it possible?

Comment: You can suppress most Maven build and execution messages for your Maven projects: **_Tools > Options > Java > Maven_**, then select **_Execution_** from the **_Categories_** list, then enter **-quiet** in the **_Global Execution Options_** field. I realize that doesn't answer your question, but it might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks skomisa. I'll give that a try.

Comment: OK. One other unrelated point is that NetBeans 12.3 does not support JDK 16. The most recent release it supports is JDK 15. Even if you are not currently having any problems with JDK 16, you may hit unexpected issues using an unsupported version of Java.

Comment: That's good information. I'm not having any issues now probably because I am starting out with a fairly simple project. I will downgrade to JDK 15. Thanks again for your help.